# change color of some words in a text field in flutter (not all; some)

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, textfield, highlight

How can I change some words color in a text form field in flutter such as any IDEs android studio , VS , VS code and other .
I would write a small Compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller) which allows you to use different inline styles using custom regex.